# Self defense flashlights through car windows

Tags: self-defense, weapons

Do these self defense flashlights work well through car windows? Sometimes I have people bang on my car window in the shady parts of town. I definitely don't want to open the window, however want some level of defense. These flashlights work well in sun daylight too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7b7uH9Bfxs

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would they work? Certainly. Would they work as intended? I doubt it. Two things to consider:

- Refraction and reflection. The light density of these flashlights is extreme and you will have to be very careful not to be blinded by your own light, which would be especially problematic while driving in the dark.
- Provocation leading to unintended outcomes. They bump your windows to tease you, so what? You will probably provoke these guys to smash your window if you play their game, which means that you gain nothing. They are teasing you to do something which justifies escalation or they would smash the window straight away.

Comment: when you car is stopped at stop light, and some crook or druggie guy bangs on car driver window, what is the appropriate way to deal while stuck in traffic? open to any solutions, thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 I would probably not do anything beyond looking at them and with a friendly yet determined face shake my head. There is not much you can do to prevent that but avoiding these areas and given you are not allowed to have a gun lying openly in your car you'd not scare anyone but rather provoke people to do more than just bumping.

Comment: mmm, depends on circumstance, you learn in life / grounds that if a bully bothers, and the kid does nothing, they will keep being pestered/beat up, life is never assured, but always stand your ground whether live or die in end, anyways question is about light through a window, will probably find another solution, like using a window wiper washer : )